# Timeout time counting does not detect input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout, keypress

I write method to reset timeout on `mouse click`, keyup and `keypress`, but I just realised that it does not check on input field so when I'm actively typing in a field it will timeout. 
Here is my code:

```
var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 10000); 
var idleTime = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
  //Increment the idle time counter every minute.
  //Zero the idle timer on mouse movement.
  $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
    idleTime = 0;
  });
  $(this).keypress(function (e) {
    idleTime = 0;
  });
  $(this).keyup(function (e) {
    idleTime = 0;
  });
});

function timerIncrement() {
  idleTime = idleTime + 1;
  if (idleTime > 4) {
    window.location.replace('/timeout.aspx');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have all the code inside the `document.ready()` function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 10000);
    var idleTime = 0;

    $(document).on('keyup', function() {
        console.log('Keyup Detected');
        idleTime = 0;
    });

    function timerIncrement() {
        idleTime++;

        if (idleTime > 4)
            window.location.replace('/timeout.aspx');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this jQuery function to detect all key presses on the page:

```
$(document).on("keypress", function (e) {
    idleTime = 0;
});
```

So your code should look like:

```
var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 10000); 
var idleTime = 0;

function timerIncrement() {
    idleTime = idleTime + 1;
    if (idleTime > 4) {
        window.location.replace('/timeout.aspx');
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
    });
    $(document).on("keypress", function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
    });

});
```

Comment: @ PredatorIWD I tried your proposal, it actually work with mousemove and it reset timer, but not with keypress inside the input field, it seems like oncewhen being inside keypress event inside  input field get isolated from document.

Comment: @Mindan Even when inside input field is should register it. Maybe you could provide the html for it here or search for some more functions that register all keypresses.